# Using Numpy to Count Numbers in a range

Tags: python, random, numpy, cumsum

I've been trying to write some code which will add the numbers which fall into a certain range and add a corresponding number to a list. I also need to pull the range from a cumsum range.

```
numbers = []
i=0

z = np.random.rand(1000)
arraypmf = np.array(pmf)
summation = np.cumsum(z)

while i < 6:
   index = i-1

    a = np.extract[condition, z] # I can't figure out how to write the condition.
    length = len(a)
    length * numbers.append(i)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Why are you creating that `index` variable you never use? What does the `cumsum` have to do with anything? What is `length * numbers.append(i)` supposed to do? (`list.append` returns `None`, and even if it returned whatever you're expecting it to, you're not assigning the result of `length * <that>` to anything.) What is the loop supposed to loop over? (Since you never modify `i`, `i < 6` will be true forever, and you'll just keep appending `0` to `numbers`.) Maybe if you can explain in pseudocode what you don't know how to write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but the easiest way to do conditions in `numpy` is to just apply them to the whole array to get a mask:

```
mask = (z >= 0.3) & (z < 0.6)
```

Then you can use, e.g., `extract` or [`ma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) if necessary—but in this case, I think you can just rely on the fact that `True==1` and `False==0` and do this:

```
zm = z * mask
```

After all, if all you're doing is summing things up, `0` is the same as not there, and you can just replace `len` with `count_nonzero`.

For example:

```
In [588]: z=np.random.rand(10)
In [589]: z
Out[589]: 
array([ 0.33335522,  0.66155206,  0.60602815,  0.05755882,  0.03596728,
        0.85610536,  0.06657973,  0.43287193,  0.22596789,  0.62220608])
In [590]: mask = (z >= 0.3) & (z < 0.6)
In [591]: mask
Out[591]: array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [592]: z * mask
Out[592]: 
array([ 0.33335522,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.43287193,  0.        ,  0.        ])
In [593]: np.count_nonzero(z * mask)
Out[593]: 2
In [594]: np.extract(mask, z)
Out[594]: array([ 0.33335522,  0.43287193])
In [595]: len(np.extract(mask, z))
Out[595]: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach to do (what I think) you're trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.random.rand(1000)
bins = np.asarray([0, .1, .15, 1.])

# This will give the number of values in each range
counts, _ = np.histogram(z, bins)

# This will give the sum of all values in each range
sums, _ = np.histogram(z, bins, weights=z)
```

Comment: I gave up on guessing the OP's intentions as hopeless, but this does seem like a pretty good guess…